# How to use .htaccess Rewrite to redirect all files with same name?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of files scattered around my server with the same name (let's call it abc.html). I want every single abc.html to be redirected to a single page (let's say /woo/xyz.html). Is there a way i can redirect all these pages to the one page without writing out each and every one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The following rule should work, if I correctly understood your question:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/abc\.html$ /woo/xyz.html [L]
```

It will redirect any request to a file `abc.html` (even in subfolders) to `/woo/xyz.html`.

Comment: Ideally, the dot should be escaped in the regex.

Comment: Oops, indeed, nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are already using mod_rewrite for other rewrites/redirects then it would be preferable to use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch`. For example, in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch /abc\.html$ /woo/xyz.html
```

Matches any URL that *ends* `/abc.html` (which includes the document root and any subdirectory). The source URL-path is a regular expression.

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect.